# Activity is Starting every time onDataChange() - Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried searching but couldn't find the solution to this.

```
playerEvent = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        playerList = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 1;
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};
playerQuery.addValueEventListener(playerEvent);
```

Every time when it's calling `onDataChange` the activity is restarting itself.
I want to keep listing the data changes in the Firebase Db so could not use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

Answer (score 1):

Please use

> addListenerForSingleValueEvent

instead of

> addValueEventListener

addValueEventListener listens to all the changes you make in your database and the code that exist in addValueListener which is "startActivity" gets triggered .
change it on all the activities in your app

Comment: tried using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent ` but still its restarting on every change.

Comment: oh, on my other screen, I was using `addValueEventListener ` and because of that, it was restarting activity. thanks, it's working now.

Comment: @Manojahirwar you are welcome. i forgot to add  that you should change it on all screen . i will edit the anser now . i am glad it worked for you

Comment: oh no its not working. I want to keep listening for the changes. but on first load only its loading the changes, but when changes are happening in the db, its not getting in the app

Comment: Suppose i have some list, which i am populating from the db. when something gets change to that list, I want it to reflact to the screen.
using `addValueEventListener` does that but not with `addListnerForSingleValueEvent`

Comment: yeah . just discovered painfully as i edited the answer . i lost my stackoverflow points for the answering the question. unless someone decides to vote again for the edited answer.  it won't show as the correct answer